# Parse the string and append the resultant values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

How to parse the following string

```
{
City = "New York";
Country = "United States";
CountryCode = us;
}
```

and append together the values inside "" and leaving out the rest of the string. I need to get the modified string as "New York, United States".

```
CFStringRef address = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, identifier);
```

When I cast `CFStringRef` to `NSString`, I get the above logged form. How will I retrieve city/country values from the string

Comment: Where do you got the string from? Why don't you use a standard data format, such as JSON? Makes everything way easier.

Comment: Your code should have dictionary object for this string. So please show your code up to necessary part that will help you and as to others..

Comment: @JeanPaulScott See my answer (and my edit).

Answer (score 0):

If you're receving this data string (probably JSON) from the web you can process the data like this (iOS 5):

```
- (void)processData:(NSData *)responseData {
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
            JSONObjectWithData:responseData
            options:kNilOptions 
            error:&error];
        NSString* city = [[json objectForKey:@"Address"] objectForKey:@"City"];
        NSString* country = [[json objectForKey:@"Address"] objectForKey:@"Country"];
        NSString* result = [city stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@",country];
        NSLog(@"%@", result); //New York, United States
    }
```

Instead, if this string is a dictionary representation, the correct format should look like this:

```
NSString *str=@"Address = {" 
                @"City = \"New York\";"
                @"Country = \"United States\";"    
                @"CountryCode = us; };";
```

So if you really want to pass from NSString to NSDictionary you can use [NSPropartyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in this way:

```
NSError* error;
NSData *dat=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;
NSDictionary *temp = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:dat options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&plistFormat error:&error];
NSString* city = [[temp objectForKey:@"Address"] objectForKey:@"City"];
NSString* country = [[temp objectForKey:@"Address"] objectForKey:@"Country"];
NSString* result = [city stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@",country];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

**EDIT** (based on your updated question):

What you posted is a dictionary, not an array. A dictionary consists of a set of elements identified by the key-value. An array consists of a set of elements identified by an index. So if the elements that are within the array are strings, you have to work on the parsing of each string. This is usually not the best way, as @FelixKling said, you should also work on standard format like json, xml etc..

Comment: on the code line `NSData *dat=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` I am getting this exception `-[__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdd7f700
2012-05-01 17:53:54.589 smartJoinder[4773:15803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdd7f700'`

Comment: continued.... `*** First throw call stack:
(0x19b0022 0x1e47cd6 0x19b1cbd 0x1916ed0 0x1916cb2 0x64a78 0x9b6a1e 0x9b6d11 0x9c88fd 0x9c8aef 0x9c8dbb 0x9c985f 0x9c9e06 0x9c9a24 0xb4e65 0x7b85c5 0x7cfcc4 0x7d3e08 0x9805c5 0x9807fa 0x121585d 0x1984936 0x19843d7 0x18e7790 0x18e6d84 0x18e6c9b 0x276d7d8 0x276d88a 0x8ef626 0x24ad 0x2425)
terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: I've just tested on my machine and it works, are you sure you're passing `str` in the correct format as a string and not as a dictionary?

Comment: The string I am getting is CFStringRef 
    `CFStringRef address = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, identifier);` When I log it directly or cast it to NSString, I get the above log.

Comment: The log is telling you that you're calling `dataUsingEncoding` on a dictionary instead of a string (the dictionary does not have that method), make sure what type of object you pass at that method. However, those examples I have given you are possible, not necessarily be directly applicable to your problem. Good luck:)

Comment: When I try to parse the string as a NSDictionary, I am able to retrieve the values as in normal case with the dictionary, but I am getting the warning NSString may not respond to objectforkey. I am really confused about the variable I am having, whether its a string or dictionary